# Python Webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from a website using Python. When I look at the source code in my browser, I can see all the things I'm looking for. However, when I download the code with BeautifulSoup, I only get parts of the data that I want.

I know BeautifulSoup doesn't work with javascript, (I don't know javascript at all) and I was wondering if there's a way to download all the raw source code (basically get a hard copy) even if parts of the site are done with javascript.

This is my code thus far:

```
 r = requests.get('https://www.example.com/example/example')
 data = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
 example1 = data.find_all("class_="example2") 
 examples = []
 for example in example1:
     examples.append(link.get('href'))
```

I know it's hard to thoroughly answer my question without the actual source code. Unfortunately I can't show the code! Hope it isn't too big of a problem.

Comment: you can use scrapy

Comment: for example in examples when you declare examples as an empty list, will no make any loop

Comment: You can use Python Selenium

Comment: BeautifulSoup has no problem with javascript. It's just that it won't execute any of it. That's all.

Comment: MadMike is correct, but it should be explained that sometimes content is rendered via the executed Javascript.  If that is the case, it would explain why you don't see it in BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution, but here are my 2 cents if you only want to parse links.

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('http://www.examples.com')
data = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
examples = []
for d in data.findAll('a'):
    examples.append(d)
```

Of course you can search for class like:

```
my_as = soup.findAll("a", { "class" : "someclass" })
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to get a full copy of a dynamic (JavaScript based) website without a browser, that's why the easiest way of getting such a copy is with a browser.

You can look into [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control the browser and download the HTML, or just run PhantomJS with [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

A very simple PhantomJS script downloading the contents of a website:

```
"use strict";
var fs = require('fs');
var system = require('system');
var webpage = require('webpage');
if (system.args.length != 2) {
    console.log('Usage: gethtml.js <url>');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    var url = system.args[1];
    var page = webpage.create();
    page.open(url, function(status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            phantom.exit(2);
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(page.content);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 500);
    });
}
```

This waits 500ms before "downloading", depending on site and internet connection this is not enough or way too much, you can improve it by waiting until PhantomJS stops downloading data for X seconds using the `onResourceReceived` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong and makes no sense:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.example.com/example/example')
data = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
aes = data.find_all("class_="example2") 
result = []
for a in aes:
    result.append(a.attrs['href'])
```

Comment: I got mixed up with the examples there sorry. my actual code work is similar to yours.

Comment: `aes = data.find_all("class_="example2")` is missing a `"` after `class_`